# Twitter posting tweet in url

Tags: url, encoding, twitter

I'm trying to use a 'tweet this page' function in a flash piece using the url 
format 'http://www.twitter.com/home?status=go+to+this+page+http://www.example.com/#/page10'.

The flash project has deep-linked urls using SWFAddress. This requires the urls to have the pound character ( http://www.example.com/#/page10 ).

I can't seem to get this to work as Twitter misinterprets the pound sign (#) and redirects to another twitter account.

I've tried encoding the url but twitter doesn't decode it before putting the text into the status form.

As my last resort I could create urls without the pound sign and have them redirect to the SWFAddress urls but I am supposed to try and fix this problem from within the swf only.

Anyone ever have the same issue. Is there something I'm missing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the www

It's a [known bug](http://code.google.com/p/twitter-api/issues/detail?id=890&can=1&q=www&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Opened%20Modified%20Component) that will not going to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

try manually replacing '#' with '%23'

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, I tried that. Twitter does not even decode that and it appears in the status field as '%23' I know that is how it should work on any other site, why not on Twitter??

Comment: I still think this is working correctly: http://twitter.com/home?status=go+to+this+page+http://www.example.com/%23/page10